# How to bypass SSL verification while using Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I've a sonarqube MS BUILD scanner that is not able to connect to a sonarqube server:

```
C:\ws\develop>SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:aaaa /n:bbb /v:4.0.0.13063 /d:sonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.aaa.bbb /d:sonar.login=****** /d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=TestResult.xml /d:sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=dotcover.html 

WARNING: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

This executable is deprecated and may be removed in next major version of the SonarScanner for MSBuild. Please use 'SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe' instead.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.4.2

Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild

Default properties file was found at C:\Tools\SonarQubeScanner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml

Loading analysis properties from C:\Tools\SonarQubeScanner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml

Pre-processing started.

Preparing working directories...

14:40:23.762  Updating build integration targets...

14:40:23.774  Fetching analysis configuration settings...

14:40:23.855  Failed to request and parse 'https://sonarqube.aaa.bbb/api/server/version': The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

14:40:23.856  A server certificate could not be validated. Possible cause: you are using a self-signed SSL certificate but the certificate has not been installed on the client machine. Please make sure that you can access https://sonarqube.aaa.bbb without encountering certificate errors.

14:40:23.857  Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1

script returned exit code 1
```

Is there a way to disable this SSL check? The certificate will not be valid(it's valid on our domain, but this agent is not in the domain due to the IT policy)

Comment: Hello J4N. Can you install the valid certificate on that machine?